# When should I choose "Cloud Service" over "Virtual Machine" on azure

Tags: azure

Looking into it I came to find out that a 1 role of 1 small compute Cloud Service is almost 60% more expensive as the same 1 small "vitual machine"...

So why should i choose to use cloud service over virtual machine?

Searching the web I came across a lot articles about this including [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/27/windows-azure-websites-web-roles-and-vms-when-to-use-which.aspx) but none were clear enough for me... the comparison in the last one is plain useless in my opnion...

Is there a "perk" that i don't know about or is not being considered? something to justify the "extra-charge" for cloud service... Does a code running on cloud service perform better than running on a virtual machine (maybe because there's less overhead)? anything?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I guess it might be cheaper to service the Web Role (since there shouldn't be any servicing to do) and it is probably easier to scale than a VM's too. I suppose you have to do the loadbalancing, updating etc. by yourself on a VM...

Answer (score 0):

I think virtual machine would be used when we need to migrate our application to the cloud and make it 'just work'. We don't need many additional effort to move our legacy code to azure if using virtual machine. But it doesn't provide the rich PaaS features comparing with cloud service such as automatically deployment, automatically update, load balance, etc.

So if we have a legacy system and we wanted to quick move to azure, then we can choose virtual machine. But if we need to manage bunch of machines, cloud service would helps us a lot and make us focus on the business logic.